# PySpark - Access Dataframe in UDF

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a DF that has every minute of timestamp and volume of each timestamp ordered by timestamp desc. while iterating through the dataframe from each timestamp, I want to find a timestamp (t_star) that the sum of volume is equal to or more than a total volume. Say, if total volume is 1500, and the `t_star` of `2023-06-13T12:31:00` is `2023-06-13T12:29:00` because the sum of volume starting from `2023-06-13T12:31:00` to `2023-06-13T12:29:00` just exceeds 1500. and I want to find a t_star of every `timestamp_utc` in the DF

```
| timestamp_utc                | volume | t_star |
|------------------------------|--------|--------|
| 2023-06-13T12:31:00.000+0000 | 654.23 |        |
| 2023-06-13T12:30:00.000+0000 | 453.12 |        |
| 2023-06-13T12:29:00.000+0000 | 500.28 |        |
| ...                          | ...    |        |
```

```
def find_t_star(df, t_zero):
  data_collect = df.filter(df['timestamp_utc'] <= t_zero).collect()
  cumsum = 0
  for row in data_collect:
    if cumsum >= total_volume:
       return row.timestamp_utc
    else: 
       cumsum = cumsum + row.volume
  

find_t_star_udf = F.udf(find_t_star, TimestampType())

df= df.withColumn('t_star', find_t_star_udf(df['timestamp_utc']))

display(df).limit(100)
```

this is my approach but unfortunately accessing Df in UDF is impossible based on my research and if there's a way to approach this problem better, I'd like to hear all options.
thank you